# Create login page only once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Greetings,

I am a new programmer in iphone development . i am making an application with Open Erp i require to a login page which occur only the first time the app is run and also a settings page to change it when required.

I have used NSUSerDefaults to access variables around classes but not sure how to save it and log in automatically the second time the app is run.

I appreciate any help available .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set object for key in NSUserDefaults as

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefaults setObject:username forKey:@"userName"];
```

and to get from defaults use -

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user_name = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

when you launch your app check for userdefauls for pre saved username if it is nil then display login view otherwise display view that you want.